# Combine only schedule and branch in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab

is it possible to combine schedule and a specific branch in a GitLab ci task like:

```
do_my_task:
  stage: deploy-it
  script:
    - do-something.sh
  only:
    - my-branch
    - schedules
```

In my case it seems the the branch restriction won't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply `refs`

```
do_my_task:
  stage: deploy-it
  script:
    - do-something.sh
  only:
    refs:
      - my-branch
      - schedules
```

[As suggested in Gitlab manual](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs-and-exceptrefs)